# Showing equation of nls model with ggpmisc

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, nls, ggpmisc

`R` package `ggpmisc` can be used to show equation of `lm` model and `poly` model on `ggplot2` ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/707145) for reference). I wonder how I could show `nls` model equation results on `ggplot2` using `ggpmisc`. Below is my MWE.

```
library(ggpmisc)
args <- list(formula = y ~ k * e ^ x,
             start = list(k = 1, e = 2))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_fit_augment(method = "nls",
                   method.args = args)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also possible to add the equation using package 'ggpmisc', assembling the character string to be parsed with `paste()` or `sprintf()`. In this answer I will use `sprintf()`. I answer the question using the example it included. I do not show this in this answer, but this approach supports grouping and facets. The drawback is that the model is fit twice, once to draw the fitted line and once to add the equation.

To find the names of the variables returned by `stat_fit_tidy()` I used `geom_debug()` from package 'gginnards', although the names even if dependent on the model formula and method are rather easy to predict. Instead of adding a plot layer `geom_debug()` echoes is `data` input to the R console. Next, once we know the names of the variables we wish to use in the label, we can assemble the string to be parsed as an R expression.

When assembling the label with `sprintf()` one needs to escape the `%` characters to be returned unchanged as `%%`, so the multiplication sign `%*%` becomes `%%*%%`. It is possible, and in this case useful to embed character strings in the R expression, but we need to escape the embedded quotation marks as `\"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)
#> Loading required package: ggpp
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate
library(gginnards)

args <- list(formula = y ~ k * e ^ x,
             start = list(k = 1, e = 2))

# we find the names of computed values
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  stat_fit_tidy(method = "nls",
                method.args = args,
                geom = "debug")
```

[image]

```
#> Input 'data' to 'draw_panel()':
#>   npcx npcy k_estimate e_estimate     k_se       e_se   k_stat   e_stat
#> 1   NA   NA   49.65969  0.7455911 3.788755 0.01985924 13.10713 37.54378
#>      k_p.value    e_p.value       x      y fm.class fm.method  fm.formula
#> 1 5.963165e-14 8.861929e-27 1.70855 32.725      nls       nls y ~ k * e^x
#>   fm.formula.chr PANEL group
#> 1    y ~ k * e^x     1    -1

# plot with formula
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_fit_augment(method = "nls",
                   method.args = args) +
  stat_fit_tidy(method = "nls",
                method.args = args,
                label.x = "right",
                label.y = "top",
                aes(label = sprintf("\"mpg\"~`=`~%.3g %%*%% %.3g^{\"wt\"}",
                                    after_stat(k_estimate),
                                    after_stat(e_estimate))),
                parse = TRUE )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Error in `check_subclass()`:
! Can't find `geom` called 'debug'

Comment: Did you run `library(gginnards)`?

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the post you linked. Use `geom_text` to add the label after extracting parameters.

```
nlsFit <-
  nls(formula = mpg ~ k * e ^ wt,
      start = list(k = 1, e = 2),
      data = mtcars)

nlsParams <-
  nlsFit$m$getAllPars()

nlsEqn <-
  substitute(italic(y) == k %.% e ^ italic(x), 
             list(k = format(nlsParams['k'], digits = 4), 
                  e = format(nlsParams['e'], digits = 2)))

nlsTxt <-
  as.character(as.expression(nlsEqn))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_fit_augment(method = "nls",
                   method.args = args) + 
  geom_text(x = 5, y = 30, label = nlsTxt, parse = TRUE)
```

Comment: For some reason, the values ware encapsulated by c(). y = c(value) e ^ c(value): `nlsTxt
[1] "italic(y) == c(k = \"49.66\") %.% c(e = \"0.75\")^italic(x)"`

Answer (score 1):

Here I have shown nls with groups using ggpmisc to add to the plots, using the current CRAN ggpmisc (v 0.3.8). This is a variation/modification of the vignette where 'stat_fit_tidy()' used a michaelis-menten fit, found [here](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/articles/model-based-annotations.html#statistics-3).
Output looks like this:
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(ggpmisc)

my_exp_formula <-  y ~ a * exp(b*x-0)
# if x has large values (i.e. >700), subtract the minimum
# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41108403/4927395

#example with nls, shows the data returned
o <- nls(1/rate ~ a * exp(b*conc-0), data = Puromycin, start = list(a = 1, b = 2))
o
tidy(o)

ggplot(Puromycin, aes(conc, 1/rate, colour = state)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", 
              formula = my_exp_formula,
              se = FALSE) +
  stat_fit_tidy(method = "nls", 
                method.args = list(formula = my_exp_formula),
                label.x = "right",
                label.y = "top",
                aes(label = paste("a~`=`~", signif(stat(a_estimate), digits = 3),
                                  "%+-%", signif(stat(a_se), digits = 2),
                                  "~~~~b~`=`~", signif(stat(b_estimate), digits = 3),
                                  "%+-%", signif(stat(b_se), digits = 2),
                                  sep = "")),
                parse = TRUE)
ggsave("exp plot.png")
```