# Use `nlsfit` within geom_smooth to add exponential line to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, machine-learning, nls

I would like to use the `nlsfit` from the `easynls` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/easynls/index.html) with ggplot2 if at all possible.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Set up subset data:

   ```
   library('ggplot2')
   library('easynls')

   x <- seq(25,97)
   y <- c(0.014, 0.016, 0.015, 0.016, 0.018, 0.019, 0.023, 0.019, 0.021, 0.017, 0.018, 0.016, 0.016, 0.020, 0.018, 0.019, 0.022, 0.023, 0.027, 0.027, 0.028, 0.031, 0.029, 0.032, 0.030, 0.030, 0.030, 0.033, 0.039, 0.038, 0.039, 0.046, 0.042, 0.043, 0.050, 0.054, 0.059, 0.064, 0.062, 0.058, 0.063, 0.069, 0.071, 0.069, 0.073, 0.071, 0.070, 0.077, 0.086, 0.077, 0.090, 0.086, 0.098, 0.108, 0.112, 0.116, 0.129, 0.120, 0.128, 0.141, 0.150, 0.143, 0.148, 0.150, 0.162, 0.162, 0.168, 0.152, 0.151, 0.161, 0.169, 0.189, 0.184)
   data <- data.frame(x,y)
   ```
2. Run NLSfit on sample data

   ```
   nlsfit = nlsfit(data.frame(x,y), model=6, start=c(250,0.05))
   nlsfit
   # $Model
   # [1] "y~a*exp(b*x)"

   # $Parameters
   #                              y
   # coefficient a           0.0061
   # coefficient b           0.0358
   # p-value t.test for a    0.0000
   # p-value t.test for b    0.0000
   # r-squared               0.9793
   # adjusted r-squared      0.9790
   # AIC                  -500.0812
   # BIC                  -493.2098
   ```
3. Plot using `plot()` with a line

   ```
   plot(x, y)
   a <- nlsfit$Parameters[1,]
   b <- nlsfit$Parameters[2,]
   lines(x, a*exp(x*b), col="steelblue")
   ```
4. Attempt to use `nls` with ggplot2 (this works - but the fit isn't as good on the full dataset)...

   ```
   ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(
          ) + geom_smooth(method="nls", formula=y~a*exp(x*b),
          method.args=list(start=c(a=250,b=0.05)), se=FALSE)
   ```
5. Attempt to `nlsfit` with ggplot2 -- doesn't work

   ```
   # Below doesn't work
   ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(
          ) + geom_smooth(method="nlsfit", formula=y~a*exp(x*b),
          method.args=list(data.frame(x, y),
                           model=6, start=c(250,0.05)), se=FALSE)

   # Warning message:
   # Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
   # unused arguments (formula, weights = weight, list(x = 25:97, y = c(0.014, 0.016, 0.015, 0.016, 0.018, 0.019, 0.023, 0.019, 0.021, 0.017, 0.018, 0.016, 0.016, 0.02, 0.018, 0.019, 0.022, 0.023, 0.027, 0.027, 0.028, 0.031, 0.029, 0.032, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.033, 0.039, 0.038, 0.039, 0.046, 0.042, 0.043, 0.05, 0.054, 0.059, 0.064, 0.062, 0.058, 0.063, 0.069, 0.071, 0.069, 0.073, 0.071, 0.07, 0.077, 0.086, 0.077, 0.09, 0.086, 0.098, 0.108, 0.112, 0.116, 0.129, 0.12, 0.128, 0.141, 0.15, 0.143, 0.148, 0.15, 0.162,
   # 0.162, 0.168, 0.152, 0.151, 0.161, 0.169, 0.189, 0.184)))
   ```

Is this possible - would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: `geom_smooth` is trying to give `nlsfit` a formula argument which it doesn't accept. Either create the model outside of `ggplot` and then use `geom_line` to plot it, or use `nls`

Comment: @RichardTelford Is it possible to pass the `nlsfit` model (see part 2) to `geom_line` ? And if so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You would need a data.frame of x values and y predictions.

Comment: `nlsfit` doesn't seem to have a predict method *i think* this will be difficult to automatically put through the method argument of geom_smooth. nlsfit also only returns a character string of the input formula so will be v. difficult to parse to create a predict method only from the model output. (also given that nlsfit uses nls under the hood I'm surprise that you get different fits). I really dont get how this makes things easy!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `stat_function` to make the last part work:

```
a <- nlsfit$Parameters[row.names(nlsfit$Parameters) == 'coefficient a',]
b <- nlsfit$Parameters[row.names(nlsfit$Parameters) == 'coefficient b',]
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) a*exp(b*x), colour = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: here is an integrated example you might like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66050809/4927395)