# How do I add an exponential trendline to various scatter plots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, exponential

first time posting a question in here.

I can't seem to find an easy way to add an exponential trendline to my various scatterplots. I have 8 tree species with different relationships of their height (in meters) and its diameter at breast height (DBH for short in cm). For now I have managed to do the different scatter plots for each tree species, but I can't seem to find a way to add an exponential trendline. [Scatter Plot of DBH - Height Relationship per Tree type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckgqT.png)

The code I used is as follows:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Height__m_,DBH__cm_)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol = 4, nrow = 2) +
  labs(title = "DBH - Height Relationship", y = "Height (m)", x = "DBH (cm)")
```

When I add the `geom_smooth` function, I can't seem to add an exponential trendline since I know these types of relationships to be the best fit. The code I've tried using is:

```
 geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula =  y ~ a * exp(b * x), aes(color = "Exponential"),
          se = FALSE, start = c(a = 1, b= 1))`
```

If there's also a possibility of adding the R2 value, that would also be welcomed.
I would appreciate the help!

Comment: What output or errors did you get then you tried the `geom_smooth` function?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41881894/6851825

Comment: There's around 17 warnings, but they all state the same: `Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50
14: In (function (formula, data = parent.frame(), start, control = nls.control(),  ... :
  No starting values specified for some parameters.
Initializing ‘a’, ‘b’ to '1.'.
Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have your data, but here's an example using the built in `Orange` dataset. In this case, setting a lower starting `b` value of 0.001 removed a warning message *(1: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
singular gradient* that prevented finding any viable fits.

```
ggplot(Orange, aes(age,circumference)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Tree, nrow = 2) +
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', 
            method.args = list(start = c(a=1, b=0.001)), 
            formula = y~a*exp(b*x), colour = 'black', se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This did it, I changed the b value to 0.001 and it now displays the exponential trends.

Comment: nice answer, +1, although I guess a more appropriate model for the sample data might be a linear model  ... ;P